# React.Children.map Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Hi I've been having this issue for few hours and I couldn't figure out the correct type for the child inside the map. I tried using `ReactElement` but it gives me an error on the first parameter of `React.Children.map()`

```js
{
    React.Children.map(children, (child: React.ReactElement, i) => {
            const id = child.props.children[0].props.id;
            console.log(id);
            return <div></div>;
        }
    )
}
```

When I try this code it's saying that

```
`Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | readonly ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[]'.ts(2345)`
```

I've added an image below been looking for the correct type if there is something maybe someone encountered this type issue? Thanks

**Note: The error in the images is when I don't assign any type on child**

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message you described is not the same as in the pictures?

Comment: Hi sorry for confusion the error in the image is when i don't assign any type for child

Answer (score 3):

In short, the `ReactNode` type is a union type for a: `ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined`.

The type error is telling you what's wrong: You're assuming the `child` is always going to be **defined** AND is an **JSXElement**/**ReactElement** with `props` with an array of `children` that has a `props` property with a defined `id` prop.

VSCode, or rather the Typescript language server, is displaying an error stating that there's no way for it to know if a child meets these requirements because you haven't put up any type guards for them. Therefore, you can't access properties on this `child` parameter when it can be `null`, `undefined`, `boolean`, `string`, `number`, and so on.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your code above, but you have to let Typescript know that only a child that [isValidElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement) can be accessed/manipulated/changed; otherwise, you're going to run into JavaScript type errors (i.e., "Can't read properties of null/undefined (reading props/children/id)"). On that note, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to access conditional properties on an object type.

Demo:

[image: Edit Typescript React Child Map]